# Proof of dual norm relation: $\frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r} = 1$

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

> Recall:
>   $\|\|$ is a norm in $R^n$, and its dual norm is defined as
>   $\|z\|^*=\text{sup}_{\|x\|\leq1}z^Tx$.

If $q$-norm and $r$-norm are dual norm, then we have the following relation:

$$\frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r} = 1$$

Ex: $1$-norm and $\infty$-norm are dual.

1. How to prove it?
2. Does this relation hold in the case for Matrix?
   (Ex: spectral norm and nuclear norm are dual)

Comment: [It holds for matrices under the Schatten $p$-norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm)

Comment: **Hint for 1:** Hölder's inequality